# How to cut rect from circle in Compose Canvas?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

When I use `BlendMode.DstOut`, it's supposed to show transparent source shape but it's black.

Supposed result:

[image: 1]

Real result:

[image: 2]

```
@Composable
fun BlendMode() {
    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().background(White100))
    Canvas(modifier = Modifier.size(300.dp)) {
        val radius = size.width / 3
        drawCircle(
            color = Color.Red,
            radius = radius,
            center = Offset(radius, radius)
        )
        drawRect(
            color = Color.Blue,
            topLeft = Offset(radius, radius),
            size = Size(radius * 2, radius * 2),
            blendMode = BlendMode.DstOut
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `blendMode` will not allow you to achieve the desired result. You can do this by using [`clipRect`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/graphics/drawscope/package-summary?hl=pt-br#(androidx.compose.ui.graphics.drawscope.DrawScope).clipRect(kotlin.Float,kotlin.Float,kotlin.Float,kotlin.Float,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.ClipOp,kotlin.Function1)):

```
clipRect(
    top = radius,
    left = radius,
    right = radius * 3,
    bottom = radius * 3,
    clipOp = ClipOp.Difference
) {
    drawCircle(
        color = Color.Red,
        radius = radius,
        center = Offset(radius, radius)
    )
}
```

Comment: Does clipRect have rounded corner property?

Comment: @ZixuanZhu no, but you can use `clipPath` and build any path, e.g. with a rounded rectangle